# Server 2012 R2 extremely slow interactively

Tags: performance, windows-server-2012-r2

I searched around for days and tried a number of suggestions to resolve this issue and still nothing has fixed it.

I have a server that essentially serves only me. I use it for testing and development. Without any interaction from me the interface is now horribly slow. It serves files fine. AD and DNS also work fine. If I try to log into the console it takes 1-3 minutes to get to the desktop when it used to take about 10 seconds. If I try to load Chrome, I get all sorts of timeout errors waiting for it to load until it finally does. Even the smallest executable takes forever to start.

Any ideas? It's a really basic setup but it does have RAID 5 enabled. It's an HP G5 server. It's only the interactive stuff that causes problems. I cannot remember all that I have tried over the last month or two. I've made sure the drivers are up to date. There's nearly no CPU utilization normally. Even starting Task Manager takes time.

Does anyone know of any issues that could cause this?

Comment: What clues do you see in the Windows Event log, especially entries logged while you're experiencing problems?

Comment: I'll check the event logs now.  Shouldn't take longer than an hour to log in and get to the logs :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a ton of time trying to work this out, I just want to post here, for posterity, that it was the ***VIDEO CARD***!  I couldn't believe it either.   No errors, nothing in the log file.  I just decided to strip down the server to its bare bones and see if that cleared anything up.   By going back to the on-board video instead of the PCI card I had put in for a bit better resolution, it all cleared up.   Thanks for the reply!